# Jenkins plugins in jruby, can't get it to work

Tags: jruby, jenkins-plugins

I've tried to get this to work on several operating systems (Windows 7, OS X and Ubuntu) and I'm about to give up on this.
I've followed the guide on https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+plugin+development+in+Ruby
On Windows 7, bundle fails until I add another "rescue" for Errno::EAGAIN in faster.rb.
When I run jpi server to test the plugins I get the following error:

```
[...]  
INFO: Injecting JRuby into XStream  
LoadError: no such file to load -- jenkins/plugin/runtime  
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038  
    (root) at < script >:1  
2012-jan-26 09:17:31 jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onTaskFailed  
SEVERE: Failed Loading plugin ruby-prototype  
hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to initialize  
[...]
```

Is this a known issue? I found that some had similar problems last year in August, the answers suggests that this is now fixed.
Suggestions or a solution to this problem would be much appreciated.

// Jens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support for windows is just poor at the moment and the plugin ruby-prototype is no longer maintained either. It seems like moving to a unix-based OS and trying out existing official ruby plugins from jenkins-ci.org is the best bet to start developing ruby plugins.